# Get selected item from dropdown menu via ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My problem is that I have a form that like:

```
<select name="Users">
  <option value=""selected>Select user to add</option>
  <% notShareWith.each do |user| %>
    <option value=<%user.id%>><%=user.name+" "+user.email%></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
<% form_for @imageuser do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id ,:value => 5 %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :image_id ,:value => @image.id %>
<% end %>
```

My drop down menu works fine and it list the users that have access. I can revoke access and everything. I have no clue how to know what option is selected from the drop down menu or how to submit that to the image users form. I am using:

```
<% form_for @imageuser do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id ,:value => 5 %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :image_id ,:value => @image.id %>
<% end %>
```

to submit the user that is selected but I need to know what the value of the selected item is so I can pass said value into:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id ,:value => 5 %>
```

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [options_from_collection_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

Something like this should work

```
<% form_for @imageuser do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(notShareWith, 'id', 'name'), prompt: 'Select user to add' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :image_id ,:value => @image.id %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) helper instead, something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, notShareWith.map { |user| user.id }, :id, :id, :prompt => 'Select') %>
```

Then, grab the selected value like: `params[:user_id]`

Answer (score 0):

To fill the selected id of user in your form you have to do several steps

First, add `id` attribute in your option

```
<select id="user_id" name="Users">
  <option value=""selected>Select user to add</option>
  <% notShareWith.each do |user| %>
    <option value=<%user.id%>><%=user.name+" "+user.email%></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

Then, you can use javascript to pass into `imageuser` form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#user_id").change(function(){
      selected = $(this).val();
      $("#imageuser_user_id").val(selected);
    });
  });
</script
```

**NOTE:**

You'd better use `select_tag` helper to create select option

```
<%= select_tag 'user_id', options_for_select(notShareWith.collect{ |u| ["#{u.name} #{user.email}", u.id]}, prompt: "Select user to add") %>
```

Comment: If I use the `select_tag` to create the select option how do I get the selected option back to pass to the `user_id` in the `form_for`